# Get order id of POS Order Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-10

I have a trouble related to POS Order.
I want to get the id of order and fill into POS bill like: **Receipt No. 001-001-001**

If I don't click on Invoice button, everything will be OK.
But when I clicked on, I can not get the id of order.
This is script I got id in Qweb:

```
<t t-if="widget.pos.db.get_orders().length > 0" >
    Receipt No. <t t-esc="widget.pos.db.get_orders()[0].id" />
</t>
```

It return empty order but in Orders report It still show the id.

Comment: I resolved! in Receipt screen we already have order variable. Just call order.uid and the id will be shown correctly